# Merging two files using matching characters

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting, merge

```
File1:
X
X
P
X
N
X
Q
File2:
P 1
N 5
Q 0

Desired output:
X 0
X 0 
P 1
X 0
N 5
X 0
Q 0
```

I have tried a lot of ways using merge command on bash. I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Note that `merge` is for 3-way merges, which is a very different thing from what you want. What you want looks more like a "left join" in database terms, except you also need a default value. For left joins, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382566/left-outer-join-on-two-files-in-unix).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in `Awk` very easily!

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ hash[$1]=$2; next}{ if ($0 in hash) $2 = hash[$1]; else  $2 = "0" }1' file2 file1
```

`Awk` works by processing input lines *one* at a time. And there are special clauses which `Awk` provides, `BEGIN{}` and `END{}` which encloses actions to be run before and after the processing of the file. Each line in the file is split based on the value of special variable `FS` (default one or more whitespaces) and those individual fields can be accessed from `$1`,`$2`..`$NF`

So the part `FNR==NR` is meant to process the first file argument provided in the command, because `FNR` keeps track of the line numbers for the both the files combined and `NR` for only the current file. So for each `$1` in the first file, the values are hashed into the array called `hash` and then when the *next* file processing happens, the part `$0 in hash` will map those lines in the `file1` where the hashed indices from `file2` are present. For such mapped lines, we print their equivalent values and for non-mapped lines we print `0`.

The `{..}1` is a short-hand representation to do `{..; print}` to basically reconstruct/print the entire line based on the modification to individual fields or to any of the said special variables.

See more of [Built-in Variables That Control awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/User_002dmodified.html#User_002dmodified)

Comment: or using ternary operator instead of `if-else` statement `awk 'NR==FNR { hash [$1]=$2 ; next} { print $1, !hash[$1]?"0":hash[$1] }' file2 file1`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `sed`, however, the `Gnu` version of the editor can make the regex less noisy.

Basic idea is to read the File2 first and store it in the hold space, with its lines being newline separated.

Then we read File1 and append the lines of File2 from hold onto the just-read line of File1. If we are able to detect the presence of File1 line in hold space, its a go, and we print File2 line as is by pruning the pattern space of other stuff.

Otherwise, we print File1 line with a 0 appended.

```
$ sed -Ee '
    / /{H;d;}
    G
    s/^(\S+)\n.*\n(\1 \S+)(\n.*)?$/\2/;t
    s/\n.*/ 0/
' File2 File1
```